# Yanking multi-line text in VIM doesn't paste into shell with line breaks

Tags: powershell, vim

Windows10, Vim 7.4

When I paste multi-line yanked text into powershell (running with ConqueTerm plugin) I lose the line breaks. Pasting the same yanked lines into another vim (.txt) window preserves the line breaks as expected.

e.g.

```
abc
def
```

yanked and then pasted into powershell window I get

```
abcdef
```

instead of

```
abc
def
```

my vimrc:

```
behave mswin
set ff=dos 

set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-command

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4

set wildmenu

let mapleader="," 

set relativenumber

nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
```

Comment: What happens, when you paste in good ol' Notepad?

Comment: @Boldewyn The yanked text isn't on the system clipboard. When I paste into another (non-powershell) vim window, the line breaks are included.

Comment: try using `"+y` (`yy`, if you're just yanking one line)

Comment: Since you have `behave mswin` in your vimrc, may I suggest using `set clipboard=unnamed` ? With this Vim can directly copy and paste from the System clipboard.